# no persister for System.Generic.List fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, persist

I will insert a list of objects in my database with the following method:

```
public static void InsertObjekts(List<Objekt> objekts)
{
     var session = SessionManager.CurrentSession;
     using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
     {
          session.SaveOrUpdate(objekts);
          transaction.Commit();
     }
}
```

But I get the erroer `no persister for System.Generic.List;`
When I iterate over my list to insert every element by own, it only goes in the first iteration, because I have then no session.
Can someone give me some tips to this topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this

```
public static void InsertObjekts(List<Objekt> objekts)
{
    var session = SessionManager.CurrentSession;
    using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        foreach(var obj in objekts)
        {
            session.SaveOrUpdate(obj);
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: great, I have try this approach but I have the commit in the foreach statement, but one question to you, do nhibernate every time a new connection to database in this case?

Comment: @Higune: the only access to database will be on transaction commit. SaveOrUpdate won't access database.

Comment: one question, the update doesn't work correct, every time it will be an insert statement

Comment: @Higune: does your objects has the id set?

Comment: do you meam the Id(x => x.Id); statement?, Yes I have

Comment: @Higune: if `id` <> 0 (or whatever value you consider as new) it shouldn't be inserting new records but updating. It might worth to open a new question adding all relevant details in there.